# Skip, or quickly return from, query if @variable is NULL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup a query to delete all but the 100 most recent records in a table, so I'm using the following query to determine the timestamp to use:

```
SELECT @time := `time`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 99,1;
```

And my intention is to use the following simple query:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `time` < @time;
```

Now, so long as there are at least 100 rows in the table this works just fine, however, if there are fewer rows then the value of `@time` is effectively `NULL`, which is no use; this is because `time < @time` seems to return every row (unlike entering `time < NULL` directly, which is a bit weird).

Anyway, my question is this; given that `time` may be `NULL` or empty, how I can either skip the `DELETE` statement in this case or, if that would be complex, how can I adjust the `DELETE` to not only delete nothing, but also to do so as efficiently as possible (i.e- no searching).

If the solution requires some kind of change to my initial `SELECT` then that's fine, so long as the logic is maintained (I want to preserve the 100 most recent entries).

Comment: are you in a stored program to use an `IF` ?

Comment: I could but I'd rather not; is there some way I could make my `DELETE` return without doing anything if `@time` is empty/NULL?

Comment: create a dummy table and test it :p